# Which version of this sentence is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

As not being an english native, I have trouble deciding which version of this sentence is correct gramatically?

*Grant special permissions to your employees to use different features of this program for a more **streamline** workflow.*

or

*Grant special permissions to your employees to use different features of this program for a more **streamlined** workflow.*

When I read this sentence out loud, the version with the **streamlined** word sounds ok to me, but some of my friends and colleagues are saying that the correct form is with the **streamline** version, because **streamlined** would be in past tense.

Comment: It should be in the past tense because it's a part of a verb used as an adjective, when we are describing something in this way we are saying that the action is complete. Compare it with "I prefer _cooked_ food"; "The new website is a _completed_ project"; "Use our electric beard trimmer for a _well-groomed_ look".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With how you have written the sentence the second one is correct. A native speaker would not use 'streamline' in that context. By saying 'for a...' you are describing the software after it has been streamlined, not the actual process of streamlining itself.

If you want to use the present tense of the verb 'streamline' you would use 'to...' instead of 'for a...' and the sentence would end like this-

Grant special permissions to your employees to use different features of this program to streamline the  workflow.